# Javascript awaiting the entire synchronous loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, nested

For performance purposes, I want to run a for loop without awaiting the code inside, but there's another function that I want to execute only after everything in the for loop is done. Here's an example:

```js
function waitForThis() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    downloadImage() // I don't want to wait for this
  }
}

waitForThis() // I want to wait for all 10 images to be downloaded
runAfter() // Run this after all downloadImage() have completed
```

If I add await in front of `downloadImage()`, I wouldn't be able to download an image until the previous one is finished, so I want to do it synchronously. Any ideas?

Comment: `Promise.all` will help

Comment: @JaromandaX that's exactly what i was looking for. thank you!